# Why is it wrong to consider the highest asymptotic point as an absolute maximum of the function?

Tags: calculus, functions, education

Given a function $F$ defined over -infinity to +infinity. The limit of $F$ as $x$ tends to plus infinity is equal to $k$, where $k$ is any constant. (asymptote)
If we suppose that $k$ is the greatest $F(x)$ possible, why can't we consider it a maximum?

Comment: it depends on $F$. $k$ will be maximum iff there is $x$ such that $F(x)=k$ and $F\le k$. If $k$ is asymptotic of $F$ but $F$ never achieves $k$, it's not maximum of $F$ (or rather $F$ does not achieve maximum in that case)

Comment: $k = \sup F(\mathbb{R})$ but $\max F(\mathbb{R})$ doesn't exist since $k \not \in F(\mathbb{R})$. See also [Relation (of infimum and supremum) to maximal and minimal elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Relation_to_maximal_and_minimal_elements).

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue to say a value is maximum if it is achieved at some $ x$. But if that value is not achieved at any $ x$, then it can't be maximum. To be called a maximum, say local maximum or global maximum, there should a neighborhood such that value of $x$, is greater than values of the neighborhood. This is why we define infimum and supremum.